# I need help in PHP with seeing if an integer is Positive or negative

Tags: php

Okay, I have done a lot of research, and still have found nothing to make this work:

> Write a PHP function called `isPositive` that takes one parameter that represents an integer and returns true when the integer is positive and false when the integer is negative. By the way, 0 is a positive number.

That is what I need to do.  I have tried different things, and yet I get nothing to make it test if my numbers are positive or negative.

Thanks for your help!

I got this, but, it does not work:

```
function isPositive($val = NULL)    // Add default to save php errors if nothing is passed
{
    if ((int)$val)          // type cast for security
    {
            if ($val >= 0)
            {
                    return TRUE;
            }
    }
}
```

Here is the other code I have tried, and still does not work:

```
function isPositive($number = NULL)
    if ($number = <0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

Comment: Please show some code. This exercise is trivial, and can be done with only very basic knowledge of PHP.

Comment: Seriously? `return $num >= 0;` is too complicated for you?

Comment: P.S. If you always cast the value to an Integer, then any time it's not an Integer (including NULL), it will become 0 and always return true.

Comment: what do  you mean "it does not work"?  Does it give you an error message?  If so, what message?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting '{' in  (it shows this right after if ($number =< 0)

Comment: Yet another option is to use gmp-sign()
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-sign.php

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to answer your question with another question:

What is the definition of positive or negative?

Positive numbers are greater than zero.

Negative numbers are less than zero.

So, how do you compare two numbers in PHP?

Is there an operator that does that?

BONUS: how do you handle zero?  is it positive or negative?

Comment: Well, positive being 0 or any number greater than 0.  0 would be a positive in this case.

Comment: And therefore.. she is a witch. Burn her!

Answer (score 4):

```
function isPositive($number) {
    return is_numeric($number) && ($number >= 0);
}
```

You can change `is_numeric` to `is_int` if you want the function to work only for integers. Let's see what's wrong with your function:

```
function isPositive($val = NULL)    // Add default to save php errors if nothing is passed
{
    if ((int)$val)          // type cast for security
    {
            if ($val >= 0)
            {
                    return TRUE;
            }
    }
}
```

1. You don't return anything if any of the two clauses fail, there should be a `return false;` somewhere in there. Your function returns `NULL` if any of the clauses fail, `NULL !== false`.
2. `if ((int)$val)` is completely wrong. You are checking if the type casting worked or not? That's not useful, what you need to check is if `$val` is an number or an integer, the simplest way to do that is with `is_int`, `is_float` and `is_numeric`. Check their manual pages for more.
3. `($val = NULL)` is completely unnecessary. You want PHP to throw an error when someone is not using the function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

like someone mentions above

```
$int = (int)-2;

function test( $int ){

    return (bool) ( $int >= 0 );
}

var_dump(test( $int ));
```

Comment: You don't need to `(bool)`, `( $int >= 0 )` evaluates to bool.

Answer (score -2):

```
function NegativeOrNot($number)
{    
    if ($number >= 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Very simple.

Comment: This is exactly the opposite of the question...

Comment: This gives me errors!  I have tried this one too!

Comment: I'm sorry for downvoting this answer because it's funny.

Comment: Sorry I just had to put to opposite, as Lobita had not included any code at the time i answered. Glad I made a programmer smile :)